# InputMethod Hides the EditText

Tags: android, android-input-method

[image]

As shown image in above I have four tabs below videoview  Resume , Produits ,Persos, Talk.

When I click on Tab a new corresponding activity is launched below the tabs.
Now as shown in Image current Tab is talk.
My question is when user clicks on Edittext it shows soft input keyboard but it hides the edittext beside the image.How to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.